# mysql does ifnull(...) hinder index usage?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with integer values and I need to query by the sum of columns:

```
    id, A, B, C
    1, 21, 32, null
    2, 9, 0, 124
    3, null, null, 6

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE B+C > 50
```

This does not work since additions with null are not allowed. The current implementation is to set all nulls to 0 and add a separate column for each column to state if the 0 actually means null:

```
id, A, B, C, A_null, B_null, C_null
1, 21, 32, 0, false, false, true
2, 9, 0, 124, false, false, false
3, 0, 0, 6, true, true, false
```

I don't think that this is very elegant and would like to make use of the ifnull function instead:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ifnull(B,0)+ifnull(C,0) > 50
```

Does this come with a great performance penalty or other disadvantages?

The table has many million rows.

Comment: You cannot use the index to lookup `where b+c>50` anyway (to be more precise: you can maybe use the index to scan and it might be used if it is a covering index; but you cannot directly find all rows with that condition). Using `ifnull ` (or actually `coalesce()`) for your calculation is perfectly fine, and will probably not even be measurable (apart maybe from actually being faster as the table size goes down). Absolutely do not add columns to mark if it is a null!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use

```
    isnull(column_name ,0)
```

This will insert a 0 into the null values and then it will allow you to SUM them.

Difference between ifnull and isnull - ifnull takes two arguments; one for if the value is null and one for if it isnt.

isnull just simply inserts a value into all the null values which i thought would be fair more simple for this question.

Comment: What's the difference to ifnull?

Comment: According to the docs isnull only takes 1 argument and returns true or false. So it is not a replacement for ifnull